# Trying to create a histogram by using a string to print out the same amount of times equal to the value of an integer user input

Tags: c#, string, integer, comparison, histogram

Im completely new to coding and I've been given a challenge to create a histogram by asking a user to input a certain amount of numbers line by line. Which I have executed a for loop to handle with no issues. The difficulty I'm having is I'm trying to use a string which I've called (x) and contains ("*"). The challenge is to make the (*) symbol duplicate to the amount of the value entered by the user... Just wondering how I could code it in such a way so that it compares the user input value number to print the (*) the same amount equal to the number being entered!

```
namespace Exercise_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] userVal = new int[8];
            string x = ("*");


        for (int count = 0; count < userVal.Length; count++)
        {
            if (userVal[count] <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter Number");
                userVal[count] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            else 
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR, Number too BIG!");
            }
        }

        for (int count= 0; count < userVal.Length; count ++)
        {




        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can your please show your work first and explain clearly where you stuck? You can read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Show us some code :D

Comment: there we go :) its a bit messy in the way its been pasted

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be to iterate through the responses, and use the string(char,cnt) constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx.

It fills the string with a specific char, and specific length.

e.g.

```
namespace Exercise_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            int numberToCollect = 10;    
            int[] answers = new int[numberToCollect];
            int numberCollected = 0;

            while(numberCollected<numberToCollect) 
            {
                int parsedInt = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(intConsole.ReadLine(),out parsedInt))
                {
                   answers[numberCollected++] = parsedInt;
                }
                else 
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("Invalid number, try again!");
                }
            }

            for(var cnt in answers) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new String('*',cnt));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! In what way could implement this into my code about to take the user input integer to create the string to print equal to the value of the integer?

Comment: So in the case of my code above the var responses could be var userVal in the case for my array? I won't be able to store specific values within the array it has to stay blank and be filled by the user input only.

Comment: I'd delete you "answer" - it's not helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Exercise_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] userVal = new int[8];


        for (int count = 0; count < userVal.Length; count++)
        {
            if (userVal[count] <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter Number");
                userVal[count] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR, Number too BIG!");
            }
        }

        foreach (var cnt in userVal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new String('*', cnt));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
 }

 }
```